# How can I remove a keyboard shortcut in TeXShop?

Tags: texshop

How can I remove a keyboard shortcut in TeXShop? For example, I have that `Alt+Cmd+C` make an action (that I really don't want to use and I don't need), and I'd like to program `Alt+Cmd+C` in the macros to give a matrix (but it doesn't work since it's already used by the program). So how can I remove the shortcut `Alt+Cmd+C` in the program to be able to use it for a macro?

Answer (score 1):

I see that Opt-Cmd-C and Opt-Cmd-V are bound to Source->Fonts->Copy/Paste Style which are indeed pretty useless. You might try to go to the Shortcuts tab of System-Prefefrences->Keyboard. Then Select App Shortcuts and add a new shortcut for TeXShop.app (you'll have to select the app from a list). Then add those two Menu commands (exactly as written---e.g., if the command has … you really need to add … (Opt-; with a US keyboard) NOT ...) and give them obscure multi-key shortcuts. That should free up the old shortcuts for use in TeXShop.